# How to repond to a kinetic impact electronically

Tags: accelerometer

Say I have a large soft surface such as a jacket and I want to register it getting hit by a paintball from a paintball gun, how would I do that? What type of sensors could I use?

Answer (score 3):

a [piezoelectric sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor) will create an electrical signal when hit. They are used in many different types of devices and would most certainly register a paintable hitting a jacket.

Comment: I recall Giotto http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giotto_mission had three on its dust shield to triangulate impacts and these being plotted in real time on the TV, though obviously that's a much faster projectile hitting a hard surface.

Answer (score 3):

Not going to be easy, i don't think an accelerometer is going to cut it.

I think the easiest answer would be to modify the jacket (or make an under shirt) which is pressure sensitive.

You could do this by using 2 layers of conductive fabric and a sparse semi insulator in between and carefully sewing it all together.  Setup a circuit to measure the resistance between the 2 conductive fabric layers and when something compresses them (such as a paintball) the resistance should drop.

Alternatively, if a paintball is really your use case, you could use a microcontroller with a little microphone somewhere on the jacket and process the audio looking for the sound of the impact.  More math work, less sewing.

Comment: Conductive fabric is the way to go. If you're using this in a paintball match, it means the person wearing it will likely have a paintball gun, which will drown out the impact sounds in the microphone option.

Answer (score 0):

How about piezo film sheet eg http://www.meas-spec.com/product/t_product.aspx?id=2488 ?